# Output of the message after sending the request

Tags: angular, forms

Please help me. I'm working with a small firm that sends one field to create a new password. If the request is successful, I get the following answer in the browser: network / fetch
[image]

Please can you show me an example of how to display a reply message? And if not, how to show a ready-made message if the request is successful? thank you very much

my console

[image]

template:

```
<div class="forgot_password_component">
   <form class="forgot_password_form" [formGroup]="forgotPasswordForm">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Type email</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="email">
  <mat-error *ngIf="forgotPasswordForm.controls['email'].errors?.required">Field can't be empty</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="forgotPasswordForm.controls['email'].errors?.email">Invalid email</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
   <button mat-raised-button color="accent" [disabled]="forgotPasswordForm.invalid" (click)="sendEmailToRestorePassword()">Restore</button>
   //Message from browser
   <span></span>
   //Ready message
   <span>A new password has been sent to the specified mail</span>
 </form>
</div>
```

ts code

```
export class ForgotPasswordComponent implements OnInit {

forgotPasswordForm: FormGroup;
subscription: Subscription;
isLoading = false;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.forgotPasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]] })
}

email() {
   return this.forgotPasswordForm.get('email')
}

sendEmailToRestorePassword() {
this.subscription = this.authService.forgotPassword(this.forgotPasswordForm.value).subscribe((done) => {
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.router.navigate(['auth', 'login'])
 })
}
```

Comment: Where does the browser message come from? does it return from `sendEmailToRestorePassword()` ?

Comment: @MernaMustafa Network / Fetch, XHR / Name / and go to the received request

Comment: You are navigating to another page after clicking `restore`, how do you want to display the message in the same page? and could you please add this line `console.log(done)` into `sendEmailToRestorePassword()` to see the result of the request in the console?

Comment: @MernaMustafa, I want to make a delay with setTimeout, and then to redirect it to the login page in 1-2 seconds, but before that I want a message to appear whether everything is fine or some problems, such as non-existent email. Can you help with that?

Comment: @MernaMustafa, The same as in the picture, I get in the console

Comment: @MernaMustafa, yes. `console.log(done)` i have correct result. Can we continue in other place, for example in social media or gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the result of the request and extract the message from it as follows:

```js
//response interface
export interface Response {
  detail: string;
}

export class ForgotPasswordComponent implements OnInit {

forgotPasswordForm: FormGroup;
subscription: Subscription;
isLoading = false;
message: string;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.forgotPasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]] })
}

email() {
   return this.forgotPasswordForm.get('email')
}

sendEmailToRestorePassword() {
this.subscription = this.authService.forgotPassword(this.forgotPasswordForm.value).subscribe((done: Response) => {
  if (done['detail'] != null){
     this.message = done['detail'];
     this.isLoading = false;
     //add your delay
     this.router.navigate(['auth', 'login'])
   }
  else{
    this.message = "fail"; //or any error message you want
  }
 })
}
```

And use binding to show the message in .html

```html
<div class="forgot_password_component">
   <form class="forgot_password_form" [formGroup]="forgotPasswordForm">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Type email</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="email">
  <mat-error *ngIf="forgotPasswordForm.controls['email'].errors?.required">Field can't be empty</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="forgotPasswordForm.controls['email'].errors?.email">Invalid email</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
   <button mat-raised-button color="accent" [disabled]="forgotPasswordForm.invalid" (click)="sendEmailToRestorePassword()">Restore</button>
   <span>{{message}}</span>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have following error: `Object is possibly null`
`if (done.detail != null){
        this.message = done.detail;`
underlined `done`

Comment: Try to use `done["detail"]` instead of `done.detail`, and if you get the same result in the pic when you tried `console.log(done)`, then it shouldn't be null

Comment: did not help, the same mistake

Comment: Does the result of the request contain only the `detail` property? or it is a complex object? if it contains more properties, please provide a pic that shows the whole returned object

Comment: I updated my question. I added photo with result in console

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Comment: I don't know why you are getting `null`, try `console.log(done.detail)` and see what it is the result

Comment: `console.log(done.detail)` - `Object is possibly null`, done underlined in red

Comment: But when you try `console.log(done)` you get a result right?

Comment: Try to run `ng serve`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241400/discussion-between-merna-mustafa-and-halland).